# How to get all content of _fields_ of a Ctypes object as ctypes array?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have defined a sample bit-field as below.

How do I get the values of _fields_ as a list/ctypes array?

```py
class packet_fields(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
               ('length_present', c_int, 1),
               ('attribute_present', c_int, 1)
               ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your question, so here's an example on how to get values:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import ctypes

class packet_fields(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
               ('length_present', ctypes.c_int, 1),
               ('attribute_present', ctypes.c_int, 1)
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pf = packet_fields()
    pf.length_present = 0
    pf.attribute_present = 1

    # list fields: name and type
    for field in pf._fields_:
        print(f"Name: {field[0]}; type: {field[1]}")

    # access value
    print(f"length_present: {pf.length_present}")
    print(f"attribute_present: {pf.attribute_present}")

    # all fields as a list
    fields_list = [getattr(pf, f[0]) for f in pf._fields_]
    print(f"As list: {fields_list}")
```

output:

```
Name: length_present; type: <class 'ctypes.c_long'>
Name: attribute_present; type: <class 'ctypes.c_long'>
length_present: 0
attribute_present: -1
As list: [0, -1]
```

If you're concerned about `-1` (rather than just `1`), replace `c_int` by `c_uint`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code.
With this code structure, you can access the array or an element in the array.

```
class packet_fields():
    liste = [
               ('length_present', "dgr1", 1),
               ('attribute_present', "dgr2", 1)
               ]
dz= packet_fields()
print(dz.liste[1])
```